# How to go to an angulaJS app that is located inside a folder

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor

This is my folder structure on the server:

[image]

How do you start the angular JS app inside the AngularJSAPP folder from index in the current folder?

```
<a href="./AngularJSApp/" target="_blank">Angular JS app</a>
```

how should the link look like?
When I tried something like:

```
    <a href="./AngularJSApp/index.html" target="_blank">Angular JS app</a>
```

the server returned code 404. it cant find the files.

[image]

```
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="services/data.service.js"></script>
<script src="services/user.service.js"></script>
<script src="services/localstorage.service.js"></script>
<script src="services/data.salescharts.service.js"></script>
<script src="directives/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/admincontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/carcontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/logincontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/saleschartcontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/registercontoller.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you run any server which is serving files from current folder?

Comment: yes. the current folder works perfect. but as soon as I click the link the browser loads but cant find any files. I can see in the devtools that it searches for all the files but comes up empty.

Comment: added a pic up top

Comment: Seems that index.html was found successfully, but scripts in that index.html have incorrect path! How scripts are added in the index.html?

Comment: added pic up top

Comment: If you just go to the AngularJSA directory and open index.html file manually - will it work correctly?

Comment: nope. under development i used lite-server to run the app. But when I test uploaded it to the server as it is right now with no other things only the Angular app content it ran. The browser creates a tree structure with the files in the head section but no content in theme. added pic

Comment: this is my index: https://paste.ofcode.org/tFpRTepVKFCenWwPvinu6U

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155628/discussion-between-allramest-and-artem-arkhipov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to information from comments.

You need to add `../` before every path.
Without that browser is trying to find files in the same directory with index.html.

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
......
```

Comment: your line of thought work, added  `../AngularJSApp/` to all filepaths. and now its spinning like a cat on the server. thank you for your help!